# Ubuntu 16.04 Error this plugin is not supported. Flash Player

Tags: flash

When I try to run flash on any website it says this Plugin is not supported

Specs:
1.9 GiB
Intel® Core™2 Duo CPU E8400 @ 3.00GHz × 2 
Gallium 0.4 on AMD RV620 (DRM 2.43.0, LLVM 3.8.0)
64-bit
155.3 GB 
(I know we have a ancient computer)

[This is the error message.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ws1Bi.png)

Answer (score 4):

Install **ubuntu-restricted-extras** package
Or alternatively **flashplugin-installer** package.

Comment: `flashplugin-installer` is sufficient if the browser is Firefox, while [adobe-flashplugin](https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/net-install-flash.html) is recommended for e.g. Chromium or Opera.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same error message (on Ubuntu 16.10). Already had **ubuntu-restricted-extras** and **flashplugin-installer** installed, but neither Firefox nor Chromium would play the flash stream.

Installing **adobe-flashplugin** (and accepting the solution of uninstalling **flashplugin-installer**) fixed the problem for me.

Comment: need [Enable the Canonical Partner repository][https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/addremove-sources.html#canonical-partner]